# bootstrap css error class is not displaying when a jquery validation error occurs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate my form that uses bootstrap 2, but when a rule is violated the error class is added but on the screen the input box doesn't look any different.  How can I get the input 'highlight' to default to bootstraps error class and display properly.

```
HERE IS THE HTML
 <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Contract Name: </dt>
      <dd>
         <input name="myInput" type="text" />
      </dd>
 </dl>


HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.validate.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


    $('.submitOCform').click(function() {                        
       if($("#submitForm").valid()) {
            document.forms["submitForm"].submit();
       }
    });

    //Load the form validation for the page    
      $("#submitForm").validate({
        rules: {
          "myInput": {
            required: true,
            maxlength:100
          }                  
        },
          highlight: function(label){
              $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
              $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success');
          },
          success: function(label){
            $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
            $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
          },
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                      error.appendTo(element.parent());
          }
      });

    }); // END DOC Ready        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `messages` attribute of the validate function and edit the **required** message. The message should be enclosed in `<code>` tags

```
$("#submitForm").validate({
    rules: {
      "myInput": {
        required: true,
        maxlength:100
      }
    }, 
    messages: {
        myInput: {
            required: "<code>Please specify something here</code>",
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a

```
<div class='control-group'></div>
```

around your input that you want to be color changed on error